# Gradient fill bitmap and CreatePatternBrush just gives black fill instead of gradient

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, gdi

I'm trying to create a Gradient Brush in windows mobile as follows:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateBitmap(16, 16, 1, 16, NULL);
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP hPrevious = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
TRIVERTEX vert[2];
GRADIENT_RECT gRect;
//... fill in vert and gRect
GradientFill(hDC, vert, 2, &gRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
SelectObject(hDC, hPrevious);
Delete(hDC);

HBRUSH hPatternBrush = CreatePatternBrush(hBitmap);
HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
SelectObject(hDC, hPatternBrush);
RoundRect(hDC, ...);
EndPaint(hWND, &ps);
```

Draw the bitmap without pattern brush

> HDC hdcSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
>   HGDIOBJ hbmOld = SelectObject(hdcSrc, hBitmap);
>   BitBlt(hDC, ..., hdcSrc, ..., SRCCOPY);
>   SelectObject(hdcSrc, hbmOld);
>   DeleteDC(hdcSrc);

This code create a round rect with a black background, not the pattern brush. I can draw the hBitmap which is used to create the brush and it draws the gradient. Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Are you sure that this code written in C# (according to tag) ?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I meant C++.

Comment: I'm suspicious of your code's complete lack of error-checking. API functions are prone to fail. If you ignore the return values, how will you know when the OS tries to tell you that something is wrong? Also, please show the code that proves that the reason for the black rectangle isn't simply because you specified two black vertices in `vert`. Please **copy and paste** your real code — no more "typos."

Comment: Copy and paste of my real code isn't possible as its wrapped behind my own API but this is the parts that make up what I'm doing. Changing RoundRect to the code above displays the gradient bitmap.